# Scala deep type cheking

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, typechecking

We have a function that can returns anything:

```
def func: AnyRef
```

And we need to check if return value is a

```
Tuple2[String, String]
```

or

```
List[Tuple2[String, List[String]]]
```

or

```
List[Tuple2[String, List[Int]]]
```

or anything else.

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Refactor to not use this stupid function?? :)

Comment: @vptheron Too much code to refactor. I hope there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If `func` is something that is under your control, I'd recommend creating a data type to represent the possible things that `func` can return, and simply return those from `func`. It goes against the idea of type safety to return "anything", so my answer will be to help bring back type safety.

```
sealed trait FuncReturnType
case class Thing1(data: (String,String)) extends FuncReturnType
case class Thing2(data: List[(String, List[String])]) extends FuncReturnType
case class Thing3(data: List[(String, List[Int])]) extends FuncReturnType
...

def func: FuncReturnType
```

Hopefully, the number of `Thing` classes is not infinite.

This way, when you call func, you can match its return value against the various `thing` classes, and you don't have to worry about type erasure (which you would have to do if you don't refactor in this way)

Comment: Thanks, in my particular case it can help. But still there is a common task.

Comment: It should not be common and, generally, for experienced Scala programmers it is not. Those types are incoherent and demand a better design.